# Cannot run angular projects after upgrading from angular2 to angular4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I had many angular 2 projects built with anular-cli beta. Now i wanted to make angular4 projects so, What i did was:

1. Updated node and npm
2. Removed angular-cli beta
3. installed @angular/cli

Now when i make a new project using `ng new project` it successfully creates it but when i do `ng serve` it gives following error.

[image]

**Output of ng --version**

[image]

**Node v 8.1.2**

**Npm v 5.3.0**

Comment: How tied to node 8 and npm 5 are you? I have tried them a couple of times with no luck. Ended up going back to [7.10 and 4.2](https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.10.0/). These work without issue. I just haven't taken the time to figure out the issues with the latest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this step

1. Unistrall Angular

   ```
       npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
   ```
2. Clear Cache

   ```
    npm cache clean
   ```
3. install Angular

   ```
     npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
   ```
4. First npm start and  Replace This Code in angular-cli.json in your Angular2 Application

   ```
   npm start 

   "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
     "environments": {
       "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
       "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
     }
   ```